# Architecture style for developing a graphical editor

Tags: architecture, graphics, editor

What architecture style is good for developing a graphical editor like MS Paint?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An architecture that supports composition, preferably of plug ins. Then you'd want to look at the command pattern for actual paint operations.

Paint.Net is open source I believe, so you could look at its source code.